# Can I set up a local network from my computer that I could then connect to with my Wii?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, wii

Due to the odd way my college's network is set up, I can't use their network with my Wii (it's a long story, and not exactly relevant to the question). However, my computer can connect perfectly fine, so is there some way I can set up a local network from my computer that I could then connect to with my Wii?

For the record, the computer I'd be using for this is a Macbook Pro, if that affects anything.

Comment: I flagged this question because even though you are asking so that you can hook up your Wii, the network related need is a bit more specific to SuperUser.com.  Specifically, I recommend buying a WiFi router and I'd hard-wire it into the dorm network.  I'm not a WiFi/networking guru, so someone over their may be able to give you a better tip on hardware and, possibly, some general step-by-step instructions.

Comment: We're missing some details about your network and Wii here.

Comment: What details in particular? As far as the wii, it's just a normal wii, there's not much (that I know of) in the way of details to give. As far as the network goes, you have to connect to their help network and enter a username and password to get authorization to connect to their main network (which actually gets you online). However, trying to connect directly to the main network won't work, but the help network doesn't register as a valid internet connection on the Wii, and so I can't connect with it to get the registration for the main network. That's why I'm trying to do it via computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up Internet Sharing in the sharing pane in System Preferences.

You will need to have both your Ethernet and AirPort (Wi-Fi) turned on in networking.

Assuming your MacBook is using a wired connection and you want to share using AirPort, choose the following:

[image: Sharing PrefPane on Internet Sharing, Ethernet to Wi-Fi]

Otherwise, you will need to buy Nintendo's [Wii LAN Adapter](http://store.nintendo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=117712&currency=USD&catalogId=10001&tranId=0&lastAction=setCurr&storeId=10001&languageId=-1&categoryId=62707&ddkey=http:SetCurrencyPreference), in which case you can try to connect directly to the network, and should that fail, you can still try Internet Sharing with your computer.

Connecting to the campus Wi-Fi then sharing over ethernet to the LAN Adapter:

[image: Sharing PrefPane on Internet Sharing, Wi-Fi to Ethernet]

Comment: My computer's connection is wifi, so the options I get are Ethernet, Bluetooth PAN and Firewire. Will one of those let my wii connect?

Comment: @Nicholas1024 Unfortunately, you can't use Wi-Fi for both. You will need to get the Wii LAN Adapter to connect to your computer via Ethernet.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try I suppose. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Nintendo used to offer a [WiFi USB Connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Wi-Fi_USB_Connector) that allowed you to share your PC network connection over WiFi, I don't know if that product is still available but searching ebay for "DS network adapter" returns similar products.

Comment: Nintendo dropped the USB Wi-Fi dongle for the DS. The only networking adapter they sell is the [Wii LAN Adapter](http://store.nintendo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=117712&currency=USD&catalogId=10001&tranId=0&lastAction=setCurr&storeId=10001&languageId=-1&categoryId=62707&ddkey=http%3aSetCurrencyPreference) for Ethernet.